# Python script to read serial port - Digi ConnectPort TS

Tags: python, serial-port, wireless, gateway

I am extremely new to Python but discovered that I need it in order to programme my *Digi ConnectPort TS1W MEI* gateway. What I want to do is read from the serial port periodically then send this data wirelessly to the nearest access point. What I have started with is trying to open, read, write and close the serial port, and I have got the following code so far:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1yq4x09xi5w4dsm/CuuZCIjwRT

But the code was not designed for my model of gateway, and the error message I received is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “WEB/python/serial_loopback.py”, line 28, in ? import serial. 
ImportError: No module named serial.
```

When running the following command through Telnet:

```
python serial_loopback.py
```

I'm not sure if any of you Python programmers out there would know how to go about fixing this sort of thing?

Comment: you're missing the [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) module. Install it and your good to go.

Comment: Ok, do you mean I have to install it onto the Digi gateway? If it is in the form of a .py file, then I guess I would just need to upload this to the gateway too?

Answer (score 0):

I think @msvalkon means you need to:

```
pip install pyserial
```

See installation docs:
[pyserial#installation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html#installation)